# Selecting price using Selenium and Python with changing classes

Tags: python, selenium

I'm pulling rates from a site by navigating to different listings, but the class is not constistant between listings:

Listing 1:

```
<div class="jss238" data-lpos="price-widget">
 <div class="jss57 jss277 jss268">
 $329.00
 <span class="jss269">/Night</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Listing 2:

```
<div class="jss501" data-lpos="price-widget">
 <div class="jss57 jss540 jss531">
 $250.00
 <span class="jss269">/Night</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

The class changes for each listing. From what I've been learning, I can select by class but it's not consistent between listings. Can I use "price-widget" as a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the prices you can do the following:

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-lpos="price-widget"]')
for price in prices:
    print(price.text.strip())
```

You can use css selector as well. In that case it will be:

```
prices = driver.find_elements_css_selectro('div[data-lpos="price-widget"]')
```

I used `strip()` to remove leading and trailing spaces from the string.
In case you want to remove the `$` sign from the string use `.replace("$", "")`, so it will be

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-lpos="price-widget"]')
for price in prices:
    print(price.text.strip().replace("$", ""))
```

Comment: This passed in one large string, but I was able to use partition to remove everything after the first new line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

use the below XPATH :

```
//span[contains(text(), '/Night')]/preceding-sibling::div
```

take everything in a list and iterate over that and get your desired element. like below :

```
price_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), '/Night')]/preceding-sibling::div")
for price in price_list: 
   print(price.text)
```